# CSS Background with 2 colors

Tags: html, css, colors, background, background-color

I want to create a background like in this example;

[image]

I tried this code

```css
.home {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    120% 100% at top left,
    #272934 61%,
    #272934 92%,
    transparent 92%
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
  <section class="home py-4" style="background-color: #1DC44F;">
    <div class="container-lg">
      <div class="row min-vh-100 align-items-center align-content-center">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49670229/8620333

Answer (score 0):

One can do shapes in CSS but not any shapes, I have tried that before and sat for countless hours, before going the svg and extra bytes route. Maybe going with an svg image rather than trying to leverage full-on CSS would be best. I would recommend the canvas / svg route, to implement it successfully, by making the custom svg in eg. Adobe Illustrator or even Figma.
You can try playing around with the CSS in [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if you want to try going the full css way.

This was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557757/should-i-use-css-or-svgs-for-displaying-shapes) on Stack a few years ago: CSS vs SVG.

Here is a [blog post](https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2015/09/01/css-vs-svg-shapes-and-arbitrarily-shaped-ui-components) on the comparison of CSS vs SVG.